# Accessing nested arrays JSON data in PHP

Tags: php

I have a JSON array like this:

```
"custom_fields": [
    {
        "label": "Customer_Info",
        "data": "10"
    },  
    {   
        "label": "Customer_Other",
        "data": "50"
    }
```

I am able to access the data and print it like this:

```
$data = $_POST['custom_fields'];

foreach ($data as $item) {
    $line = '';
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'data'){
            $line .= "$key: $value, ";
        }
    }
    $current .= rtrim($line, ', ')."\n";
}
```

And then I get an output like:

```
data: 10
data: 50
```

Problem is, I want to get only the `data` value where the `label` is `Customer_Info` so that I just have a string with the value `10`. How do I do that?

Any help is greatly appreciated before I lose the last few remaining hairs :/

Comment: Prepend `if ($key == 'label' && $value != 'Customer_Info') continue;` into inner `foreach`?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast what if, for some reasons, `data` is **before** `label` ?

Comment: @Cid fair point.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Thanks for your help, too. The API where I get the data from isn't supposed to change, but you never know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to nest loops. 1 `foreach` is enough. Check the values in `$item`

```
$data = array(array("label" => "Customer_Info",
                    "data" => "10"),
              array("label" => "Customer_Other",
                    "data" => "50"));

$line = '';
foreach ($data as $item)
{
    if (isset($item['label'])
        && isset($item['data'])
        && $item['label'] == 'Customer_Info')
    {
        $line .= "data: {$item['data']}, ";
    }
}
$current = rtrim($line, ', ')."\n";
echo $current;
```

Output :

> data: 10

Answer (score 0):

If there will be only one with a `label` of `Customer_Info`, it would be easier to extract the `data` values and index on the `label` values:

```
echo array_column($data, 'data', 'label')['Customer_Info'];
```